# Taylor Series of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, geometric-series

[image]

I think that I would use the Taylor series but I'm not sure where to start. I know that that Taylor series is equal to
$$
\frac{f^{(n)}(p)}{n!} \cdot (z-p)^n
$$
but I'm not sure how to use this fact.

[(-1)^n n!/ (2+i)^n+1]/n! *(z-1-i)

how does this equal f(z)?

Comment: The taylor series of $f$ is unique and since $f$ is analytic in a neighborhood around $p$, it should suffice to check that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(p)}{n!} \cdot (z-p)^n=f(z)$ given the hypothesized $f^{(n)}(p)$ (hint: the series is a geometric series)

Comment: it's not working out for me could you please elaborate

Comment: Could you write out what you get for the Taylor series (using the hypothesized $f^{(n)}(p)$ that you are given) in your post? Then it'll be easier to spot where you are stuck.

Comment: You have to sum that expression you wrote from $n=0$ to $\infty$